# Display Image in Gridview Boundfield Cell conditionally

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have a `Gridview` which is having 2 columns : ***plan value*** and ***actual value***.

I am getting data from a table. I need to display up or down arrow image in 2nd column (after the value) based on the values as shown below :

```
| plan | actual |                       

| 40    | 50 ^  |
```

That is if actual > plan then show up arrow after value in actual column down arrow in opposite case.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You have to provide little bit more information about the problem. How you bind the data to gridview? Are you using template fields?

Comment: How do you bind the data ? (i.e DataTable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Territories"><ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Literal ID="litActual" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

C# Code:

```
    void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Literal litActual= (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("litActual");

    if(Convert.ToInt32( ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem)["actual"]) > Convert.ToInt32( ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem)["plan"]))
      litActual.Text = ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem)["actual"].ToString() + " <img src="upimageurl"></img>";
   else
    litActual.Text = ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem)["actual"].ToString() + " <img src="downimageurl"></img>";

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am simply using boundfield to bind the data from table.
<asp:BoundField DataField="PLAN" ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Plan" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PLAN" />
And in code behind, i am using datasource to bind the gridview.

Comment: Thaks Kapil, your solution helped me.